# Android dynamically adding images from xml into gridview

Tags: android, android-layout

Okay so here my issue, I
 have a list of items that when a user clicks one, it gets added to a shared preference file which looks like this: `<map>
<string name="Some Name">R.drawable.somename</string>
</map>`

Using this code:

```
prefEdit.putString(title[position],imgString[position]);                        
                prefEdit.commit();
```

What I want to do is place R.drawable.somename from the xml file into a grid view as an image in place of:

```
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.archery, R.drawable.aviation,
            R.drawable.archery, R.drawable.aviation,
            R.drawable.archery, R.drawable.aviation,
            R.drawable.archery, R.drawable.aviation,
            R.drawable.archery, R.drawable.aviation
    };
```

Currently the user can select up to 130 different items that they can add to the grid view.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to just have the xml store the base name, ("somename", "archery", "aviation"). Then you could get the id doing this.

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("archery", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

In this example if your drawable was R.drawable.archery then id would = R.drawable.archery. You could store the strings in the xml and get the ids this way.

Comment: Sorry I must have too many things going on in my head cause I still can't figure out how i get from `<map> <string name="Archery"archery</string> </map>` in my preference file to int `id = getResources().getIdentifier("archery", "drawable", getPackageName()); `

Comment: figured it out thanks:`String Archery = mPref.getString("Archery", "");int IntArchery = getResources().getIdentifier(Archery, "drawable", getPackageName());private Integer[] mThumbIds = {IntArchery};`